# Gigya PHP Sdk - Comment Notifications

Tags: php, sdk, comments, hmacsha1, gigya

I'm trying to use the Gigya's Comment Notification functionality and I've followed the guidelines at:
http://developers.gigya.com/010_Developer_Guide/18_Plugins/022_Comments_Version_2/Comment_Notifications

I've developed the following code:

```
<?php

    require_once('GSSDK.php');

    $event = $_POST['event'];
    $eventData = $_POST['eventData'];
    $nonce = $_POST['nonce'];
    $timestamp = $_POST['timestamp'];
    $signature = $_POST['signature'];
    $signatureBase = sprintf("%s_%s_%s_%s", $event, $eventData, $nonce, $timestamp);
    $expectedSignature = SigUtils::calcSignature(
        $signatureBase,
        MY_SECRET_KEY);

    if($signature !== $expectedSignature) {
        header('HTTP/1.0 403 Forbidden');
        die();
    }

    //Some other stuff
    exit();

?>
```

But it never gets to the "//Some other stuff" part. 
Always the expected signature differs from the signature provided by the Gigya's server.
What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try the following code instead:

```
<?php

  static function calcSignature($baseString,$key)
  {
    $baseString = utf8_encode($baseString);
    $rawHmac = hash_hmac("sha1", utf8_encode($baseString), base64_decode($key), true);
    $sig = base64_encode($rawHmac); 
    return $sig;
  }

  function checkSignature() 
  {
    $event = $_POST["event"];
    $eventData = $_POST["eventData"];
    $nonce = $_POST["nonce"];
    $timestamp = $_POST["timestamp"];
    $signature = $_POST["signature"];

    $signatureBase = $event . "_" . $eventData . "_" . $nonce . "_" . $timestamp;
    $secret = "[your gigya secret key]";
    $expectedSignature = calcSignature($signatureBase, $secret);        

    // Now compare the expectedSignature value to the signature value returned in the callback
    if ($signature !== $expectedSignature) 
    {
      header('HTTP/1.0 403 Forbidden');
      die();
    }
  }

  checkSignature();
  //Some other stuff
  exit();
?>
```

This code removes the dependency on GigyaSDK just to check the signature. The method provided is the same method that the GigyaSDK uses, but the advantage here is that this is a much smaller memory footprint since the entire GigyaSDK does not need to be loaded.

Additionally, I'm not sure if it was intentional, but your comparison has the code:

```
if(!$signature !== $expectedSignature) {
```

Instead of:

```
if ($signature !== $expectedSignature) {
```

I'm not quite sure what the purpose of the extraneous logical-NOT operator on $signature is supposed to accomplish, but it seems like this would cause unexpected behavior.

Comment: Jay, I've tested your solution but is not working.
The payload is comming in $_POST vars, there's nothing in $_GET.
Yes, indeed the `(!$signature !== ` was a typo error.
I've fixed that in the ref code and still does not work.
The signature generated by calcSignature differs from the signature coming un the request (POST field "signature")

Comment: If you allow me to, I can send you by email the last payload that I've received and you can check that. Also I will need your email :)

Comment: I've update the answer provided above to change it back to $_POST, there is a disconnect between our documentation and how this used to work.  Formerly this data was provided in the $_GET payload and it is documented that it works this way.    The documentation is incorrect as you have noted, it should be $_POST not $_GET.

Comment: As an additional note here, check your Gigya Partner Secret Key -- it must be the Partner level secret key, not an application or user key.  In the code above you should change:

`$secret = "[your gigya secret key]";`

so that it looks something like 

`$secret = "qxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxI=";`

Comment: I have tested again and again. And using some code provided by the mail support I was able to find the problem.
It seems like our server it's urldecoding the "+" character as a white space in the signature passed by POST.
I finally made it work by applying some string replacement method at the value of the "signature provided" ($_POST["signature"]).